# How to reload FastAPI app when a file, other than *.py files, changes?

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

I want my FastAPI app to reload when a `.csv` file in the same directory changes.

I tried the following command, but it isn't working.

```
uvicorn main:app --reload --reload-include *.csv
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [Uvicorn documentation](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#reloading-with-watchfiles), you can install [watchfiles](https://pypi.org/project/watchfiles/), and use `--reload-include`, as well as `--reload-exclude`, to specify other file extensions. For example:

```bash
uvicorn main:app --reload --reload-include *.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [Uvicorn Documentation](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#reloading-without-watchgod), `--reload-include` does work only if optional dependency [Watchfiles](https://pypi.org/project/watchfiles/) (previously called watchgod) is installed.

Try installing it with `pip install watchfiles` and then run uvicorn again

Comment: See accepted answer.  The "watchgod" package was renamed to "watchfiles".